# My App downloaded from the playstore fails to call web service

Tags: web-services, cordova

I recently developed a cordova App that is uploaded to google play store. I tested this app on my mobile and simulators for weeks and everything works fine. However, when i download the same app from the playstore it fails to call any of the web services and such doesn't display any content.

> cordova : 9.0.1
>
> npm : 6.10.1
>
> cordova-android : 7.0.0

I have gone through every line of code and i can't seem to find the problem, i replaced every single call to `window.localStorage` to a global variables just to be able to fix what i thought would be the problem.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?></code>
<widget defaultlocale="en-US" id="com.test.fr" version="1.0.6" android-versionCode="100050" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps">
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="windows-target-version" value="8.1" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="android">
        <icon src="www/res/icon/android/fr_mobile_icon.png" density="ldpi" />
        <icon src="www/res/icon/android/fr_mobile_icon.png" density="mdpi" />
        <icon src="www/res/icon/android/fr_mobile_icon.png" density="hdpi" />
        <icon src="www/res/icon/android/fr_mobile_icon.png" density="xhdpi" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" version="2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-websql" version="0.0.10" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" version="2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" version="4.3.3" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="handset" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="local" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="17" />
    <preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="29" />
    <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
    <plugin name="cordova-custom-config" spec="5.1.0" />
</widget>
```

Worst part.... No error shown on the device, it just doesn't work.

Comment: are you sure you are using correct URL to connect?

Comment: I am very sure of the url.. the local copy of the apk file works on all my devices.. but once uploaded to the store.. it just fails

Comment: Have you implemented the production debug?

Comment: can you please explain what you mean by production debug. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to the `<application>` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` or as below using `config.xml`

```
<platform name="android">
  <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
      <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
  </edit-config>
</platform>
```

> **android:usesCleartextTraffic** Indicates whether the app intends to use cleartext network traffic, such as cleartext HTTP. The default
>   value for apps that target API level 27 or lower is "true". Apps that
>   target API level 28 or higher default to "false". [More info](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic)
>
> **Cleartext** is any transmitted or stored information that is not
>   encrypted or meant to be encrypted. When an app communicates with
>   servers using a cleartext network traffic, such as HTTP, it could
>   raise a risk of eavesdropping and tampering of content which is why in latest Android devices, it's set to `false` by default.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to figure out what is the output of this error. To allow debug on a release build use `android:debuggable` on `application` tag at `AndroiManifest.xml` (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element).

Then, plug the device to your computer and in dev settings (on your device) enable `usb debugging`. Then, navigate to `chrome://inspect/#devices` - your device should be appearing and will be a link to your webview.

With the inspector openned, do the request and look to the error on console tab.

I think there's a high chance that the error is a CORS error, may your production server has CORS eabled and then you need to use `cordova-plugin-whitelist` correctly to send a `origin` to the server, read more about `cordova-plugin-whitelist`here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/